# Equivalent metrics and open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a space and $d, d'$ be two metrics on it. I am trying to see if this is true or false: $d$ and $d'$ are strongly equivalent (meaning there are $C_1, C_2>0$ such that $C_1 d'(x,y)\leq d(x,y) \leq C_2 d'(x,y)$) if and only if for every $x\in A$, $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that$$B_{d'}(a,\delta_1)\subseteq B_d(a,\varepsilon)\subseteq B_{d'}(a,\delta_2).$$ I think this is false, and my counterexample is the following: let $X=\mathbb{R^n}$, $d$ be the usual Euclidean metric and $d'=\min\{d, 1\}$. Then $d$ and $d'$ are not equivalent, but, given $\varepsilon>0$, we can take $\delta_1=\min\{\varepsilon, 1/2\}$ and $\delta_2=2$ for example and we get the inclusion of the balls as above.

My question now is the following: if I add the assumption that also for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $\delta_0$, $\delta_1$ with $$B_{d}(a,\delta_1)\subseteq B_{d'}(a,\varepsilon)\subseteq B_{d}(a,\delta_2),$$ is my statement now true? I could prove that, under this extra assumption, the open sets for both metrics coincide, but this doesn't imply that they are equivalent, right? The metrics on my example above produce the same open sets but are not equivalent. Any comment is welcome!

(I edited the counterexample; it was not correct, as pointed out by someone who for some reason ended up deleting the comment.)

Comment: It turns out that $d$ and $d'$ *are* equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand why that is true; I could take a sequence of points with Euclidean as big as I want to and that could not be controlled by any multiple of the $\min$ norm, as it is bounded by 1. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Please tell me first what is your deinition of equivalent metrics.

Comment: In this context it means strongly equivalent, i.e. there are $C_1, C_2>0$ such that $C_1 d'(x,y)\leq d(x,y) \leq C_2 d'(x,y)$

Comment: You should have stated that from the start. I assumed that you meant that they were topologically equivalent. That's the usual meaning of the expression.

Comment: Sorry! You're right. I'll edit the question so that it is clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65949/discussion-between-dlc-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Answer (score 1):

Let's see first what it means that $d_1$, $d_2$ give the same topology:

The condition is: for every $x\in X$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta_x> 0$ so that :
$$d_1(x,y) < \delta_x \implies d_2(x,y) < \epsilon \\
d_2(x,y) < \delta_x \implies d_1(x,y) < \epsilon $$

A stronger condition ( what you wrote above) is : for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that 
$$d_1(x,y) < \delta \implies d_2(x,y) < \epsilon \\
d_2(x,y) < \delta \implies d_1(x,y) < \epsilon $$

But this is weaker than the condition : the fraction $\frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)}$  ( $x\ne y$ ) is  bounded below and above. As an example, consider the two bounded distances on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$d_1(x,y) = \frac{ |x-y|}{1 + |x-y|} \\
d_2(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{|x-y}}{ 1 + \sqrt{|x-y|}}$$

We see there exists a homeomorphism from $[0,\infty)$ to itself so that 
$$d_2(x,y) = \phi(d_1(x,y))$$ so the second stronger condition holds. However, the quotient $\frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)}$ is not bounded.